# iOS7 on "touchmove", prevent fixed element going negative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll, touch

I have a fixed row of indicators (slider-indicators) that when it reaches the bottom bound, it should sit on top of the footer. On the desktop everything works fine, and I know that on iOS the scrolling freezes the DOM manipulation.

So I tried using on('touchmove') event, which does a decent job, but when the user scrolls up the page on iOS, moving the website itself up (and revealing the blank/grey/ background), the fixed element moves with it also.

I'm try to disable this feature, and usually works with removing the touch event off('touch'), but how would I rebind it again, so that the DOM manipulation works as the user scrolls?

This is what code I have:

```
$(window).on('touchmove',moveIndicators);
$(window).scroll(moveIndicators);

function moveIndicators() {
var d = $(document).height(),                   
    w = $(window).height(),                     
    s = $(this).scrollTop(),                    
    bottomBound = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) ? 119 : 50; 
    $location = $('.location-nav');            

  if(d - (w + s) <= bottomBound) {
      $location.css({ bottom: bottomBound - (d - (w + s)), 'margin-bottom': '0px' });
  } else {
      $location.css({ bottom: 0, 'margin-bottom': '0px' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle. We can run it on device and it will be easy to replicate the issue.

Comment: @SiddharthaGupta, thanks for the reply. I will try to get one up later. But, for now it seems that for touch devices, if I just removed the (d- (w+s)) calculation, and just set bottomBound directly, it seems to resolve the issues.